# Subdomain V/S Different TLD - SEO

Tags: seo, google-search

I own example.com, example.net, example.co, example.info etc. of my brand. (13 tld/cctld/gtld in total).

I need a wordpress blog, a status page (https://www.statuspage.io/) and my main website. My main website is coded from the scratch and is mostly static. My main website is on a server managed by a known server management company and I trust them to maintain the security of the server.

My Questions -

1) Should I use example.blog or blog.example.com ? Or use example.com/blog and proxy(ProxyPass in apache) it to another server. Wordpress cannot and will not be on the same server as my main website as I see it like a time bomb (security wise). I'm not wise enough to maintain and keep-up with its security problems. I will obviously read some tutorials on what to do and what not to do, but you get my point.

2) My status page should be example.info or status.example.com ? Considering cloudflare has https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/ and not status.cloudflare.com.

Please tell me what's healthy SEO wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're aiming for SEO - make sure everything is on one root domain. Sub-domains or separate domains will simply split any equity you are earning for ranking the domain as a whole.

Put all the content you can onto one domain - use a /blog directory.

It doesn't matter what your status domain is. It'll have to be a separate domain from your main one in order to have the DNS resolve to your secure status server. Since the only critical thing is that people are aware and can find it, go nuts! Pick whatever you think fits.